# hiding empty columns in table html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a table which I need to basically look in each table and say, if one column is fully empty, hide the column and the header with the column. I will show my table, and an example to follow.

table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <h4>FULFILLED ORDERS</h4>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Order Number</th>
                  <th>FN</th>
                  <th>LN</th>
                  <th>COMPANY</th>
                  <th>PHONENUM</th>
                  <th>EMAIL</th>
                  <th>BRANCHNUM</th>
                  <th>Shipping Address</th>
                  <th>Billing Address</th>
                  <th>CITY</th>
                  <th>POSTAL CODE</th>
                  <th>STATUS</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% if(data.length){ 
                  for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
                <tr>
                <td><%=data[i].NUMF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].FIRSTNAMEF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].LASTNAMEF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].COMPANYF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].PHONENUMF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].EMAILF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].BRANCHNUMF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].SHIPPINGADDRESSF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].BILLINGADDRESSF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].CITYF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].POSTALCODEF%></td>
                <td><%=data[i].STATUSF%></td>
                <% }
                  }else{ %>
                      <% } %>
               
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

PHONENUM column is empty, I need to hide that column and the header with it so its not just headspace in my table.

thanks for the help!!

Comment: That sounds like pretty basic Javascript or jQuery to solve this. There should be tons of posts available on this. I would just google the solution!

Comment: why don't you just remove it from the template?